# How to send multiple file to webservice

Tags: c#, web-services, multipartentity

I have a webservice written by C#

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult PostFileToServers(HttpPostedFileBase[] files)
    {
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            var fileStorage = @"C:\Users\Aka\Dropbox\SMAC\file-upload";

            if (!Directory.Exists(fileStorage))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(fileStorage);

            var fileName = Path.Combine(fileStorage, string.Format("{0}.wav", DateTime.Now));
            file.SaveAs(fileName);
        }

        var jsonResponseModel = new JsonResponseModel();
        jsonResponseModel.Status = (int)ResponseStatus.Successful;

        return Json(jsonResponseModel);

    }
```

I want to send multiple file in android through above webservice. It is my code but it didn't send file to Webservice. Anyone have solution for that ?

```
public void uploadtoserver(String filepath1,String  filepath2,String filepath3) throws IOException
{


    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpResponse response = null;

            HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost(URL);

            MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity( HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE );
            File file1 = new File (filepath1);
            File file2 = new File (filepath2);
            File file3 = new File (filepath3);

            entity.addPart("files[0]", new FileBody(file1));
            entity.addPart("files[1]", new FileBody(file2));
            entity.addPart("fIles[2]", new FileBody(file3));
            httpost.setEntity(entity);
            response = client.execute(httpost);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've check something about android, It's not depend on your POST API
To send one file to server you need to "open" a HTTPUrlConnection, and FileInputSteam to read file, the code like below

```
public class HttpFileUpload implements Runnable{
    URL connectURL;
    String responseString;
    String Title;
    String Description;
    byte[ ] dataToServer;
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;

    HttpFileUpload(String urlString, String vTitle, String vDesc){
            try{
                    connectURL = new URL(urlString);
                    Title= vTitle;
                    Description = vDesc;
            }catch(Exception ex){
                Log.i("HttpFileUpload","URL Malformatted");
            }
    }

    void Send_Now(FileInputStream fStream){
            fileInputStream = fStream;
            Sending();
    }

    void Sending(){
            String iFileName = "ovicam_temp_vid.mp4";
            String lineEnd = "\r\n";
            String twoHyphens = "--";
            String boundary = "*****";
            String Tag="fSnd";
            try
            {
                    Log.e(Tag,"Starting Http File Sending to URL");

                    // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
                    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)connectURL.openConnection();

                    // Allow Inputs
                    conn.setDoInput(true);

                    // Allow Outputs
                    conn.setDoOutput(true);

                    // Don't use a cached copy.
                    conn.setUseCaches(false);

                    // Use a post method.
                    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

                    conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");

                    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);

                    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"title\""+ lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(Title);
                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

                    dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"description\""+ lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(Description);
                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

                    dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + iFileName +"\"" + lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                    Log.e(Tag,"Headers are written");

                    // create a buffer of maximum size
                    int bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

                    int maxBufferSize = 1024;
                    int bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    byte[ ] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                    // read file and write it into form...
                    int bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                    while (bytesRead > 0)
                    {
                            dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable,maxBufferSize);
                            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0,bufferSize);
                    }
                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                    // close streams
                    fileInputStream.close();

                    dos.flush();

                    Log.e(Tag,"File Sent, Response: "+String.valueOf(conn.getResponseCode()));

                    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

                    // retrieve the response from server
                    int ch;

                    StringBuffer b =new StringBuffer();
                    while( ( ch = is.read() ) != -1 ){ b.append( (char)ch ); }
                    String s=b.toString();
                    Log.i("Response",s);
                    dos.close();
            }
            catch (MalformedURLException ex)
            {
                    Log.e(Tag, "URL error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
            }

            catch (IOException ioe)
            {
                    Log.e(Tag, "IO error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
            }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}

public void UploadFile(){
    try {
      // Set your file path here
        FileInputStream fstrm = new FileInputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/DCIM/file.mp4");

     // Set your server page url (and the file title/description)
        HttpFileUpload hfu = new HttpFileUpload("http://10.20.16.67:27010/Home/PostFileToServers", "my file title","my file description");

        hfu.Send_Now(fstrm);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // Error: File not found
    }
}
```